# Macro to insert picture in cell creates a link which results in 'The Linked Image cannot be displayed' error

Tags: image, vba, excel

I am using the below to insert an image in a cell and resize with that cell. However, when I send it to someone who doesn't have access to the drive it is linked to I get the 'Linked Image cannot be displayed error'. I would like to 'break' this link and save the pic within the document. I have read that I need to use shapes rather than images but am struggling to get this to work. Can you help? Thanks.

```
Sub InsertPicture()
 Dim sPicture As String, pic As Picture

 sPicture = Application.GetOpenFilename _
 ("Pictures (*.gif; *.jpg; *.bmp; *.tif), *.gif; *.jpg; *.bmp; *.tif", _
 , "Select Picture to Import")

 If sPicture = "False" Then Exit Sub

 Set pic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(sPicture)
 With pic
 .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
 .Height = ActiveCell.Height
 .Width = ActiveCell.Width
 .Top = ActiveCell.Top
 .Left = ActiveCell.Left
 .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
 End With

 Set pic = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Comment: Try to use [Shapes.AddPicture Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198302.aspx).

Comment: Hi Fadi. I've tried this but I can't work out how to adjustment needed to the code. I've tried dozens of iterations and googled tons of examples but I keep getting a debug.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub InsertPicture()
     Dim sPicture As String

     sPicture = Application.GetOpenFilename _
     ("Pictures (*.gif; *.jpg; *.bmp; *.tif), *.gif; *.jpg; *.bmp; *.tif", _
     , "Select Picture to Import")

     If sPicture = "False" Then Exit Sub

     Dim Rng As Range: Set Rng = ActiveCell


     ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(sPicture, msoFalse, msoTrue, _
       Rng.Left, Rng.Top, Rng.Width, Rng.Height).Placement = xlMoveAndSize

 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @fadi. This is exactly how I wanted it to work. I was making it more complicated than it needed to be.